# Entity object Refresh

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm upgraded the EntityFramwork version from 4 to 6. Some of my code lines are broken now.

It's seems that the Refresh Method is missing in EF6. Is this true?

```
EntityContainer.ManagedInstance.Entities.SearchEngineBankDeposits.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, this.InnerObject);
```

The Error:

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SystemLayer.DataLayer.SearchEngineBankDeposits>' does not contain a definition for 'Refresh' and no extension method 'Refresh' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SystemLayer.DataLayer.SearchEngineBankDeposits>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is example for code that worked in the previous version of EF.

How I'm can fix this broken line?
My target is to update the current object with fresh information that comes from server.

Thank you.

Note: Please ignore that I'm using singlethon object context. I'm planing to fix this in the further.